# Debugger not started in the VS2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis-7.5, visual-studio-debugging

I have developed web application in `.NET framework 3.5 in VS 2008`, hosted in `IIS` under application pool `ASP.NET 4.0 Integrated pipeline mode`.
When I start debugging by hitting `F5` button, it throws the `error` and `debugger is not started`.

[image]

But, If I open the same application in `VS2010` and `VS2013` and start debugging, the debugger started successfully.

If I browse the application's URL in the IE, it runs successfully. My problem is debugger not started in the VS2008.

```
What are the settings to be checked/changed to get working?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have fixed by enabling the windows authentication for the respective website in IIS.
```

**Refrrence:**

1) http://blogs.iis.net/brian-murphy-booth/visual-studio-2008-unable-to-debug-asp-net-app-on-iis-7-0

2) http://forums.iis.net/t/1165570.aspx